# McNemar's Test for repeated sex ratio data

Tags: logistic, repeated-measures, proportion, mcnemar-test

I have proportion data (sex ratio of a dioecious plant) for a population that was measured three times. I would like to know if a McNemar's Test is the most appropriate analysis to answer the question: Does sex ratio changes significantly among censuses? It is important to clarify that we did not ID individuals, but only counted the number of female and male plants in each census, and individuals cannot change from male to female or vice versa (as seen in some plants). Sample size increases because as time goes by, more plants start producing flowers. My data looks like this:

```
              C1      C2     C3 
Males         74      123    132
Females       44      71     75
```

I have been trying to compare Census 1 vs. Census 2, and then C2 vs. C3. I am not sure how to correctly construct the contingency table for the McNemar's Test.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't kept track of which measurements were taken on the same units, you cannot use any within-units analytical technique, e.g., McNemar's test.  You will have to use a regular logistic regression model.  If you know the times of the censuses, you can use those as a continuous predictor; if not, you can use census as a categorical variable.  The assumption of independence is violated here, so your SEs, CIs, and p-values will be compromised, though.

Comment: If the assumptions of independence are violated, the model is meaningless. Shouldn't be any model be recommended?

Comment: @StudentT, the beta may be sufficiently informative for people to go through the process. But, the SEs, CIs, & p-values will be compromised (by how much, we don't know).

Comment: Do you mean that the dependent variable in your logistic model is the probability of sex ratio changes significantly? If so, this doesn't answer directly the question "Does sex ratio changes significantly among censuses"?

Comment: @StudentT, you can't tell if the proportion changes between censuses 'significantly', but you can get odds ratios, etc. That is either a helpful piece of information or it isn't. But since the assumption of independence is violated, you can't trust your SEs, CIs, or p-values.